# How to train model for Background removal from images in Machine Learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

Given a dataset of images, I need to segment foreground objects from the background for each image. the dataset is images of "Cars" . The output image should be just the car without any background from the original image. Can some please guide me to what are the broader steps needed to train this model ? What would be the algorithms needed . I will be using tensorflow as implementation . An example of desired functionality can be found at https://www.remove.bg/

Comment: Have you tried anything? You might not get whole ready made answer here. We can help you if you are stuck anywhere in the code.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet . Reason been since it will be a POC i wanted to narrow down my research and try to deliver this with minimum workaround time !!! Sorry for this unprepared stage . Any help is appreciated ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep learning based semantic segmentation can be used to segment foreground from the background. You need annotated data like this http://cocodataset.org/#explore for training the DL model. VGG16 based semantic segmentation can extract precise edges of the foreground objects.

Answer (score 3):

Opencv has some built in modules that can do this in a general sense it isn’t perfect though. Just lookup opencv background subtraction, if you want a way more reliable method then I would use human object detection/segmentation algorithm that can detect people.

Second, You could also use a segmentation algorithm such as Mask RCNN and to create masks of what you class as foreground, removing anything you then class as background.

Or, YOLACT: Real-time Instance Segmentation check out on github.